# logging module : Displaying correct logger name for multi - logger

Tags: python

i have a question concerning the `logging( )` module or rather the correct use of logger names :

i actually have this script `Logger.py` for my logger configuration :

```
Logs_Standard_Logger = logging.getLogger( 'Standard' )
Logs_Standard_Logger.propagate = False
Logs_Standard_Logger.setLevel( logging.DEBUG )

# print( Logs_Standard_Logger.isEnabledFor( logging.WARNING ) )

class MyFilter:

    def __init__( self, level ):
        self.__level = level

    def filter( self , logRecord ) :
        return logRecord.levelno == self.__level
        
Logs_DEBUG_FH_Enabled = True

Logs_DEBUG_Formatter = logging.Formatter('[{levelname:^9}] {name} | Method : {module} | Line : {lineno} | MSG : {message}', style='{' )
Logs_DEBUG_Logger = logging.getLogger( 'Standard.Debug' )

Logs_DEBUG_Handler = logging.FileHandler( filename = 'logs.log' )
Logs_DEBUG_Console = logging.StreamHandler( )

if( Logs_DEBUG_FH_Enabled == True ) :
   
   Logs_DEBUG_Handler.setFormatter( Logs_DEBUG_Formatter )   
   Logs_DEBUG_Console = logging.StreamHandler( )
   Logs_DEBUG_Console.setFormatter( Logs_DEBUG_Formatter )
   logging.getLogger( 'Standard' ).addHandler( Logs_DEBUG_Console )
   
else :
   Logs_DEBUG_Console.setFormatter( Logs_DEBUG_Formatter )
   logging.getLogger( 'Standard' ).addHandler( Logs_DEBUG_Console )

Logs_Standard_Logger.addHandler( Logs_DEBUG_Handler )

# Applying Filters To The Corresponding Handlers

Logs_DEBUG_Handler.addFilter( MyFilter( logging.DEBUG ) )
Logs_DEBUG_Console.addFilter( MyFilter( logging.DEBUG ) )
```

I will call the logger via a seperate file, here the `myapp.py`, this is the content :

```
import Logger
import logging

def main( ):

   logger = logging.getLogger( 'Standard' )

   logger.debug("This should be written, because levelno != debug")
   logger.info("This should be written, because levelno == info")  # <--- !
   logger.warning("This should not be written, because levelno != warning")
   logger.error("This should not be written, because levelno != error")
   logger.critical("This should not be written, because levelno != critical")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If i now execute the `myapp.py`, i get the following result :

```
[  DEBUG  ] Standard | Method : myapp | Line : 8 | MSG : This should be written, because levelno == debug
[  INFO   ] Standard | Method : myapp | Line : 9 | MSG : This should be written, because levelno == info
```

Basically, this is fine, but i wonder, why everytime on the output the logger name `{name}` is `Standard`. I would wish, it would represent the effective logger, like `Standard.Debug` or `Standard.Info` here.

Do you have some advices and are there some thing i can improve ?

Best regards
NumeroUnoDE

Comment: Is there nobody who can give me an advice please ?